# Appbar visible even in fullscreen?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to create an appbar, like the task bar, that docks at the top of your desktop.

But right now, when a program goes fullscreen, either the program obscures my appbar, or the appbar obscures part of the program wanting to go fullscreen.

Is there some way to force a fullscreen program to avoid using certain areas of the screen, so I can have both the appbar and all of the program window visible at the same time?

Comment: Whic technology are you using to create your form `Winforms`, `WPF` or `Silverlight`?

Comment: I'm using Winforms right now, could change it if another technology has the solution.

Comment: If an application sets its window coordinates to fullscreen, then it gets a fullscreen window. You just have to deal with that.

Comment: I assume that by "full screen" you mean maximized? So you want to know how to affect the Screen.WorkingArea?

Comment: No, I meant fullscreen like Firefox in F11 mode or full screen media players. But if Raymond Chen says there is no solution...

Comment: IF an app creates a borderless window and maximizes it then Windows assumes the user has no decent way to move the window anywhere.  Which is pretty accurate.  And allows the window to overlap any taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you could go with this or indeed if it's what your looking for but...

### With a main grid->

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="MyImage" ImageSource="Assets/Screenshot (1).png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
```

### And an AppBar (this ones at the bottom)->

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0" Opened="bottomAppBar_Opened" Closed="bottomAppBar_Closed">
        <Grid>
```

### And in the code behind->

```
private void bottomAppBar_Opened(object sender, object e)
    {
       this.LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,90);
       this.MyImage.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
    }

    private void bottomAppBar_Closed(object sender, object e)
    {
        this.LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

It squishes the main page up out of the way of the appBar.

Just have fun trying...